# Mysql multi select with excluding row

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Have 2 tables:

```
A(`A_id`,`A_name`)
```

and

```
B(`B_id`,`A_id`,`B_kind`)
```

`B_kind` column is `ENUM('type 1','type 2')`. So, how can I get all rows `A` which have an entry in table `B` with a `B_kind='type 1'` but without `B_kind='type 2'`.

Representation in php:

```
$A = array();
$B = array();
$sample = array();
foreach( $A as $key => $value )
{
    if( find_type1($value,$B) && ! find_type2($value,$B) )
    $sample[] = $A;
}
```

Please, help, how can I do that?

Comment: By "without" do you mean rows in A which do NOT have a row in B where b_kind = 'type 2' OR do you simply mean rows in A with a b_kind ='type 1' regardless of whether there is a b_kind = 'type 2'?  Those are different queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `exists` and `not exists`:

```
select  *
from    A
where   exists
        (
        select  *
        from    B
        where   B.A_Id = A.A_Id
                and B.B_kind = 'type 1'
        )
        and not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    B
        where   B.A_Id = A.A_Id
                and B.B_kind = 'type 2'
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM A
JOIN B ON (A.A_id = B.A_id AND B.B_kind = 'type 1')
```

Comment: that's not what he asked you're not excluding row with type_2

Answer (score 1):

I take it you want to exclude rows from A which have both an A_id of 'type 2' and an A_id of 'type 1' in B?

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A
INNER JOIN B as B1 ON (B1.A_id = A.A_id AND B1.B_kind = 'type 1')
LEFT JOIN B as B2 ON (B2.A_id = A.A_id AND B2.B_kind = 'type 2')
WHERE B2.A_id IS NULL
```

The 'IS NULL' in the WHERE clause ensures that only rows that don't match the 'LEFT JOIN' are included.